# Yotzros and Musaf for the 4 Parshios

Tags: minhag, synagogue, four-parshiot, nusach-ashkenaz, yotzrot

Are there any Nusach Ashkenaz Shuls that say Yotzros or Musaf on the weeks of the [Four Parshios](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_Shabbat#The_Four_Parshiyot)?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=14StXjr0Jf8 a bizarre rendition

Comment: https://thelehrhaus.com/commentary/would-the-rav-approve-of-the-soloveitchik-siddur/#ftnt2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems the Yekkis have

http://www.data-genie.com/ashkenaz/home.php?n=Main.Minhogim

Comment: Baltimore's old German shul, Shearith Israel Congregation a.k.a. Glen Avenue Shul a.k.a. Rabbi Hopfer's Shul, follows a mix of German customs and generic Ashkenazic practices. I believe they do some of the extra liturgy you describe.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, there are many who still do (though unfortunately a minority today). To name a few, Fifth Avenue Synagogue says the Musaf piyutim as does OZ on West Side (or at least they did last time I was there for Parshas Shkalim about 9 years ago), one or more of the Young Israels in the NY area do (I forgot which one but I know that at least one does it). In Brooklyn, there are a whole bunch of shuls that do so incl. nusach ashkenaz shuls (though the majority of those who say yotzros today daven sefard). Breure's in Washington Heights of course says all the piyutim as do a number of other shuls there. In Europe, many of the old shuls follow the minhagim as they were before the war and say yotzros (incl. the main shuls in London, Budapest, Strasbourg, Zurich, Basel...all of which daven ashkenaz)

Comment: yotzer, Welcome to mi.yodeya, and thanks very much for all of this excellent data! We'd love to have you as a fully-registered member, which you can accomplish by clicking register/login, above. This will ensure that all of your contributions are collected under one user ID, even if you come in from different computers.

Answer (score 4):

An interesting example is the Yerushalmi shuls in Israel, who follow the customs of Tamidei HaGra.  (I think the Tukachinsky luach mentions this custom.)

They don't say Yotzrot or Krovot during the brachot of Shma or Shmone Esrei, but after Shacharit (and before taking out the Torah) they say the piyyutim.

Answer (score 4):

All  the shules under Rav Teitz in Elizabeth, New Jersey have said all Yotzros for over seventy years

Comment: JEFF STRASHUN, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for the data point. I hope you stick around and enjoy the site. You may wish also to [register](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account: that will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Answer (score 3):

I have heard that Ner Yisrael says the Mussaf for Shkalim and Hachodesh as do many shuls that follow the yeshiva's minhagim. Anyone have first-hand experience?

I also heard from a number of people (but again, I have not been there to confirm) that Lakewood says many of the piyutim for Arba Parshios. Anyone know exactly which ones they say?

I know that Chofetz Chaim Adas Bnei Israel in Baltimore says the piyutim in Shachris and Mussaf for Arba Parshios.

Kesher Israel in Washington, DC says just the Mussaf on Parshas Hachodesh (and not Shkalim), a remnant of the original custom at the shul.

All these places daven Ashkenaz.

Comment: Re "I have heard that Ner Yisrael says the Mussaf for Shkalim and Hachodesh as do many shuls that follow the yeshiva's minhagim. Anyone have first-hand experience?": Yes. Agudas Israel of St. Louis [Missouri] uses _nusach Ashk'naz_, generally (AFAICT) follows NIRC's customs, and says these (and not the _yotz'ros_ of _shacharis_ of the four _parashiyos_).

Comment: do they also say Krovetz on Purim?

Comment: aaron, they do IIRC.

Comment: Ner Yisrael does indeed. I vividly remember that every year, they would start the first of the Mussaf piyutim, and everyone in the beis midrash would remember and start scrambling for the right place. Or new people would be completely befuddled for a little while.

Comment: Actually a number of Baltimore shuls do it, maybe because of Ner Yisrael.

Answer (score 1):

Also, GGBH (Golders Green Beis Hamedrash, also known as Munks) say most piyutim from the polin version of the roedolheim yotzros. Hendon Adas Yisroel say the piyutim that are in Chazoras HaShatz but not in Birkas Kriyas Shma.

Answer (score 1):

Rabbi Shafran's shule (formerly in Randallstown, MD), a/k/a Adath Yeshurun-Mogen Abraham, a/k/a the Shadover or Shadova Shule, used to say them for the 4 parshiyot and all chagim.