# Why are there musafos for sh'kalim and hachodesh, but not zachor or para

Tags: tefilla, prayer-book, four-parshiot, musaf

Why are there *musafos* (things added to the *chazaras hashatz* of *musaf*) for *Shabas parashas sh'kalim* and *hachodesh* but not *zachor* or *para*? (Or, at least, many *nusach ashkenaz* and *nusach sefard* *sidurim*, including *Rav Yaakov* Emden's, have the former but not the latter.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [this article](http://shituf.piyut.org.il/story/1384) (Hebrew).

The *piyutim* (*shivatot*) classically recited by *nusach* Ashkenaz at *musaf* of *shekalim* and *hachodesh* (although now omitted by many, many congregations) were composed by the Kalir.

The author notes that the Kalir actually composed many *shivatot* for all of the *arba parshiyot*, but he claims that for some reason, only two (for *shekalim* and *hachodesh*) had arrived in Europe by the 11th century, where they were recited at *musaf*.

He proves this from the fact that R. Meir Shatz of Worms felt the need to compose *shivatot* (in the style of the Kalir) for the two missing *shabbatot*. However, reciting these *shivatot* never became accepted as mainstream *minhag* Ashkenaz.

What is even more surprising is that some of the Kalir's *shivatot* for *zachor* and *parah* did eventually make it into Ashkenaz in the 12th century (they appear in Ashkenazi manuscripts and are the subjects of Ashkenazi commentaries) but they were never adopted as part of *minhag* Ashkenaz.

Bottom line, the answer is that there are no *piyutim* recited at *musaf* of *zachor* and *parah* because the Kalir's *piyutim* were not available in Ashkenaz when *minhag* Ashkenaz was getting started, and later developments (R. Meir Shatz's composition or the subsequent arrival of the Kalir's *piyutim*) were not sufficient to change the status quo.

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5494/yotzros-and-musaf-for-the-4-parshios?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

This is a question that I am aware of that the Levush asked and left it as "there is a need for a reason why there was no Takana of Musafim for Parshas Zachor and Parshas Parah.

See link of Elya Raba 685:14

http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7767&hilite=171f6b96-23cf-46a0-8606-29300ae1edf4&st=%D7%96%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%A8&pgnum=434