# Marovis on Yom Tov

Tags: minhag, yom-tov, maariv, nuschaot, yotzrot

Does anyone know of shuls that still say Marovis (piyutim) on Yom Tov nights?  I'm particularly interested in any place in Teaneck.

Many seem to think that it's a yekki minhag but it's pretty clear that they were said throughout Europe. (Mishna Brura takes it as a given that they are said whenever yom tov falls on a weekday when he discusses what is said on the other night if one of the nights is shabbos)

They are also printed in all standard machzorim, and would add a lot to the Yom Tov davening, yet it seems hard to find shuls that still say them.

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/5494/759

Comment: Might I suggest you [offer a bounty](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/privileges/set-bounties), aaron?

Comment: This question is tagged "yotzrot", but should actually tagged "piyut" since yotzer refers to a piyut that is recited at the beginning of yotzer or. Colloquially, all piyutim are called yotzeroth is some circles, but I find that this is ironically used by people who never recite yotzer.

Comment: I see that the Artscroll Machzorim print piyutum throughout Maariv, so it’s common enough that they felt it was worth printing.

Comment: Rav Joseph Soloveitchik's minyan at the Maimonidies school in Boston, MA says them https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/933169/rabbi-avraham-gordimer/sukkos-and-the-mysterious-simchas-yom-tov/ (I've heard reasons other than in that source for the decision, but the fact remains they say them at his direction.)

Answer (score 6):

[Congregation Etz Chayim](http://www.etzchayimtoledo.org/) in Toledo, Ohio says them.

Comment: I didn't realize there was an Orthodox Shul in Toledo. Awesome!

Comment: @SethJ I only visited there once and they are a very small but very warm community.

Comment: Those two characteristics usually go hand-in-hand.

Comment: Thanks for that response. It's amazing how the small community in Toledo preserves this age-old Minhag while many (perhaps most) people I've spoken to in some very large Jewish centers don't even know what Marovis is.

Answer (score 4):

I do not know about Teaneck, but the following is a list of shuls that I know about that say *ma'arovith* in the New York area. All these *minyonim* say the *Ashkenaz* (German) version printed in the Rödelheim *machzor*. Ma'arovith is recited on all *yomim tovim* with the exception of *Rosh haShonoh* and *Yom Kippur*.

According  to the Frankfurt, A.M. custom they are recited even on Friday nights. (marked by *)

- *K'hal Adath Jeshurun, 85-93 Bennett Ave, New York, NY
- *K'hal Adath Jeshurun of Monsey (KAJMO), 2 Dover Ter., Monsey NY
- Cong. Sha'arei Hatikvah, 711 W 179 St., New York, NY

  - Sometimes there is no *minyon* on *yom tov*
- *Fort Tryon Nursing Home, Overlook Ter. & W 190 St., New York, NY
- *K'hal Adath Jeshurun of New Hempstead, Marcia Lane, New Hempstead, NY

  - Intermittent, but ususally meets on *yom tov* except *Simchath Torah*

Answer (score 3):

[Hendon United Synagogue](http://www.hendonsynagogue.com/) in the UK says them. That is the shul I have grown up going to.

Answer (score 3):

KAYJ of Jerusalem says them. As does Kehilas Ashkenaz of Bnei Brak. As does KAJ of Beitar. As does the Yekkish minyan in Kiryat Sefer.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Barry and thanks for this first answer. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: For those of us who have never been to these Shuls, what are KAYJ and KAJ, and what shul is the Yekkish minyan in Kiryat Sefer a part of?

Answer (score 2):

Fifth Ave. Synagogue in New York (Manhattan) says them. I heard this first hand from their Chazan, Cantor Malovany.

Answer (score 1):

The GGBH (Munks') in Golders Green says them.

Answer (score 1):

Hendon Adas Yisroel Synagogue says them.

Comment: Thanks for the info! It may be worthwhile to edit your three answers into one (just so they take up less room on the page; note that the most of the vertical space taken up by each of the answers is occupied by the meta-info like your username rather than the text of the answer itself). But that's just my personal style preference, and I don't know that anyone else agrees with me. More importantly, though, it would be helpful if you'd edit in info as to whether this synagogue is Yekke, since the asker seems to grant that Yekkes say _maariviyos_. (And the same for your other answers.)

Comment: @msh210, Hendon Adas was founded as a Jekkisch schul. I don't know if it still is

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt It is not yekkish anymore (much) - and it was founded following Minhog Berlin.